# Argument-array without environment variables?

Tags: objective-c, c

I'm creating a small C-program and would like a char pointer array holding only the arguments the executable was started with.
Currently this code also outputs all environment variables:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
   while(argv) {
      NSLog(@"Parameter %s\n", *argv);
      argv++;
   }
}
```

Comment: Change while(argv) to while(*argv). That will give you just the arguments.

Comment: That was fast. Please decide whether you want to post that as an answer or if I should delete the question altogether!

Comment: @Charlie Burns That would probably cause memory violation since you first have to unreference elements to know if you're still in range. A for loop using argc does the job better.

Comment: @Virus721, no argv is zero terminated.

Comment: @CharlieBurns Are you talking about strings pointed by each element of argv or argv itself (i.e an extra element (of a pointer size) set to 0 ?

Comment: @Virus721, extra element. Yes, it's true.

Comment: @CharlieBurns Well it might be a confusing practice for people not aware about this unnatural extra element.

Comment: I don't know about 'unnatural'. It's the way it's defined. Seems pretty natural to me.

Comment: c style strings are zero terminated, not non-char arrays, that's the reason why argc is provided. There is not need for an extra element if you know the length.

Comment: Arrays of pointers are often ( not always ) null terminated. It's a very common C idiom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `while(argv)` to `while(*argv)`. That will give you just the arguments.

`main()` is actually called like this `main(int argc, char **argv, char **environ)`

What is happening is you are going past `argv` and into `environ`. This behavior
is undefined should not be relied on. Your code, as it is, will also keep on going past environ
and won't stop, you'll be printing garbage.

You can, of course, do it the other way:

```
for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
  NSLog(@"Parameter %s\n", argv[i]);
}
```

`argv[0]` contains the program name, the rest are the arguments.

Comment: Straight thinking - _I don't know about 'unnatural'. It's the way it's defined. Seems pretty natural to me._

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing the cycle the way you do, use argc. The size of argv array is `argc`, with the first value `argv[0]` being how the name of the program being executed.

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
   for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
      NSLog(@"Parameter %s\n", argv[i]);
   }
}
```

Your code is also dumping the environment variables because they are supplied as an additional parameter after argv. In fact you are accessing memory out of bounds for argv and it is pure luck this works.

Comment: Isn't `argc` the length of `argv`, like it is in C? meaning that, in your code `argv[i]` will be out of bounds on the last iteration?

Comment: Then you won't mind my edit, changing _"The size of argv array is `argc + 1`"_, I hope

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem of course not. It seems I have forgotten the fact that argc includes the name of the executable too.